# Inconsistent font size inside Tables in LATEX

Tags: latex

I am facing a sudden increase in fontsize inside a table in my document.

```
Here, the scheme stands for the protocol used to establish the connection. Hostname implies the domain name or the IP Address of the host where the server runs. Port is the TCP port on which server is found, while path gives the provision of additional data facilitating the identification of a specific server. The mapping can be better understood in the table \ref{Tablemapping}.
 
  \begin{table}[ht]
  
  \begin{center}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|p{8cm}|} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
    \hline
      \textbf{URL Field} & \textbf{Mapping} \\  
      \hline
     scheme & Scheme maps to the SRV record service field. Currently following mappings are defined. In this thesis, we are using the opc.tcp mapping.
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
     \hline
     opc.tcp & \textunderscore opcua-tcp.\textunderscore tcp.\\
     \hline
      opc.wss & \textunderscore opcua-tls.\textunderscore tcp.\\
      \hline
      https & \textunderscore opcua-https.\textunderscore tcp.\\
       \hline
     \end{tabular}\\
      \hline
       hostname & Maps on to the target field of the SRV Record\\
        \hline
        port & Maps to the SRV record port field \\
        \hline
        path & Maps on the path string specified in the TXT record\\
        \hline
        
    
    
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{\textit{DiscoveryUrl} to SRV and TXT Record mapping\citep{Part12}}
    \label{Tablemapping}
  \end{center}
  \end{table}
```

And the corresponding image is as shown here :
[LatexObservation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K28O.png)

Please guide me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\resizebox` for anything that contains text! Of course this will mess up the font size!

If you would like your table to fill the whole line, you can use a `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    
Here, the scheme stands for the protocol used to establish the connection. Hostname implies the domain name or the IP Address of the host where the server runs. Port is the TCP port on which server is found, while path gives the provision of additional data facilitating the identification of a specific server. The mapping can be better understood in the table \ref{Tablemapping}.
 
  \begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|X|}
    \hline
      \textbf{URL Field} & \textbf{Mapping} \\  
      \hline
     scheme & Scheme maps to the SRV record service field. Currently following mappings are defined. In this thesis, we are using the opc.tcp mapping.
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
     \hline
     opc.tcp & \textunderscore opcua-tcp.\textunderscore tcp.\\
     \hline
      opc.wss & \textunderscore opcua-tls.\textunderscore tcp.\\
      \hline
      https & \textunderscore opcua-https.\textunderscore tcp.\\
       \hline
     \end{tabular}\\
      \hline
       hostname & Maps on to the target field of the SRV Record\\
        \hline
        port & Maps to the SRV record port field \\
        \hline
        path & Maps on the path string specified in the TXT record\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{\textit{DiscoveryUrl} to SRV and TXT Record mapping\cite{Part12}}
    \label{Tablemapping}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]